# Java Factory pattern

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, factory

I have module A and module B each one have some specific services and i have a module C that don't have any dependencies to A and B so what i want is to call services from modules A and B and I want to acheive that using factory pattern.

in module C i have created this interface and it will be a common interface to be implemented in modules A and B

```java
public interface ThirdPartyCallsStrategy {
    void apply(String orderId);
}
```

And this is example of factory class and will provide the appropriate instance needed based on type parameter

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CoreCallsFactory {

    private static final String A_PACKAGE = "com.testA.service";
    private static final String A_CLASS = "TestClassA";
    
    private static final String B_PACKAGE = "com.testB.service";
    private static final String B_CLASS = "TestClassA";
    
    @SneakyThrows
    public ThirdPartyCallsStrategy createThirdPartyCallsStrategy(String type) {
        Class<?> clazz;
        if (type.equals("A")) {
            clazz = Class.forName(String.format("%s.%s", A_PACKAGE , A_CLASS ));
            return (ThirdPartyCallsStrategy) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        }

        if (type.equals("B")) {
            clazz = Class.forName(String.format("%s.%s", B_PACKAGE , B_CLASS ));
            return (ThirdPartyCallsStrategy) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

`ThirdPartyCallsStrategy` is implemented in different services in different modules

And finally in module C, i make the instanciation through java reflection but this will be at runtime and it can through exceptions later at runtime and not at compile time

```java
public String checkStatusAndRedirect(String orderId, String type) {
    boolean status = checkStatus(orderId);
    StringBuilder paymentResultUrl = new StringBuilder(frontUrl + "/public/payment/status?success=");
    
    if (status) {

        coreCallsFactory.createThirdPartyCallsStrategy(type).apply(orderId);
        paymentResultUrl.append(Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        paymentResultUrl.append(Boolean.FALSE);
    }
    return paymentResultUrl.toString();
}
```

So what i need is a cleaner way to change this implementation.

Comment: Maybe use a `Map<String,String>` that maps from the `type` to the format string generated by `String.format("%s.%s", A_PACKAGE , A_CLASS )` and `String.format("%s.%s", B_PACKAGE , B_CLASS )` respectively?

Comment: It's always possible to do better, but what do you really mean by "cleaner way"?

Comment: i don't want to work with java reflection due to its performance degradation problem

Comment: Why don't you create the exact type without the reflection?

Comment: Side note: when you use a `StringBuilder`, use it consistently. Instead of `new StringBuilder(frontUrl + "/public/payment/status?success=");`, use `new StringBuilder().append(frontUrl).append("/public/payment/status?success=");`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is like:

```
public interface FactoryProducer<T> {
  public T create(String param);
}

public class Factory<T> {
  Map producers = new HashMap<string, FactoryProducer<T>>();
  public void registerFactory(String key, FactoryProducer<T> producer) {
    producers.put(key, producer);
  }
  public FactoryProducer<T> getFactory(String key) {
    return producers.get(key);
  }
}
```

This way you can build FactoryProducers and Factories and keep everything decoupled.

Comment: Why do you use a paramerize type for **FactoryProducer** instead of using **ThirdPartyCallsStrategy** as a return type of create method?

Comment: @Abned The FactoryPattern as I've written it here removes the use of reflection, and parameterizing the FactoryPattern you make sure that if you only want FactoryPatterns that create objects of type `Foo`, you can parameterize the FactoryPattern and the Factory

Answer (score 0):

**Use Java SPI.**

### Define the interface `com.modelc.ThirdPartyCallsStrategy` in model C.

```
public interface ThirdPartyCallsStrategy {
    void apply(String orderId);

    String type();
}
```

### Implement `ThirdPartyCallsStrategy` in model A and model B.

```java
public class AStrategy implements ThirdPartyCallsStrategy {
    public void apply(String orderId) {
        // Do something here.
    }
    public String type() {
        return "A";
    }
}
public class BStrategy implements ThirdPartyCallsStrategy {
    public void apply(String orderId) {
        // Do something different here.
    }
    public String type() {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

### Register your implements in META-INF.

In the file of model A `resources/META-INF/services/com.modelc.ThirdPartyCallsStrategy`:

```
com.modela.AStrategy
```

In the file of model B `resources/META-INF/services/com.modelc.ThirdPartyCallsStrategy`:

```
com.modelb.BStrategy
```

### Create your factory in model C.

```java
public class CoreCallsFactory {
    private final Map<String, ThirdPartyCallsStrategy> strategyMap;

    public CoreCallsFactory() {
        strategyMap = new HashMap<>();
        ServiceLoader<ThirdPartyCallsStrategy> strategies = ServiceLoader.load(ThirdPartyCallsStrategy.class);
        for (ThirdPartyCallsStrategy strategy : strategies) {
            strategyMap.put(strategy.type(), strategy);
        }
    }

    public ThirdPartyCallsStrategy createThirdPartyCallsStrategy(String type) {
        ThirdPartyCallsStrategy strategy = strategyMap.get(type);
        if (strategy == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no strategy for this type: " + type);
        }
        return strategy;
    }
}
```

model A and B depend on the interface in model C, but model C don't know model A or B.

Comment: This is the right way to go. But when the OP is using Java modules (it’s not clear whether this is meant by “module” in the question), there is no need to deal with `META-INF/services/…` resources. Instead, module A will declare `provides ThirdPartyCallsStrategy with AStrategy;` in its `module-info.java` and likewise module B declares `provides ThirdPartyCallsStrategy with BStrategy;`, and module C has to declare `uses ThirdPartyCallsStrategy;` in its `module-info.java`